# Decrement a NewRelic Custom Metric counter

Tags: newrelic

I want to measure outgoing open  HTTP Connections with NewRelic

with

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.IncrementCounter("IncrementCounter");
```

I can create custom metric with which i increment a counter.  But I can't finde a api for decrement a counter (When connection is closed)

How can I decrement the counter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no DecrementCounter method to go along with IncrementCounter.  Instead you can use the [RecordMetric](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/net-agent-api#record_metric) method to send up a metric with the current connections, which will need to be either read when the method is called or contained in another variable.  The RecordMetric method doesn't store anything it only tells the agent to include that value along with the other data for the current transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i hoped there would be a better solution. I'll do it that way

Comment: I stumbled across this answer while looking for the solution to the same problem and I must say that doсumentation covering the API still leaves much to be desired.